# Nginx: unexpected 404 page in php

Tags: nginx, php

This is from my NGINX configuration file

```
location / {
index index.html index.htm index.php;
try_files $uri $uri/ /profile.php?nno=$uri&$args;
}
```

So, when file does not exist on the server, Nginx server http://example.com/requested_file_name

Php script **profile.php** checks the **reguested_file_name** in the database and shows user profile if username exists. If not:

```
if($count != 1) {
header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
include_once 'header.php';
?>
<div id="error">Profile not found</div>
<?php
include_once 'footer.php';
die;
}
```

It was wotking fine for years. I just got a new server with Nginx 1.10.1 version and there is a problem.

When username does not exist in the database, Nginx displays default 404 page instead of

```
<div id="error">Profile not found</div>
```

When I remove line

```
header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
```

everything works fine.
So, how do I force NGINX not to show the default 404 page but the script output?

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    fastcgi_ignore_client_abort off;
    fastcgi_connect_timeout 60;
    fastcgi_send_timeout 180;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 180;
    fastcgi_buffers 4 256k;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
    fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
    fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;
   }
```

Comment: You have `fastcgi_intercept_errors` turned on. Have you tried turning it off?

Comment: Post it as an answer and I will accept. It works.